# Is it bad practice to have two exact same @ExceptionHandler in two different @RestController classes?

Tags: spring-mvc, exception, spring-restcontroller

I have two @RestController classes, `@RequestMapping("/persons")` and `@RequestMapping("/person")`, both of them can throw PersonAccessException which is a custom exception. and is handled by @ExceptionHandler
There are also going to be more @RestControllers in future that may throw this exception and just like how it is not ok to write same method again and again in different places I'm not sure if it's ok to copy and paste this exact same exception handler in different rest controllers.

I'd like to know if there's anyway to write it once and use it from different classes, like a normal method.

Comment: https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/web.html#mvc-ann-controller-advice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it bad practice to have two exact same @ExceptionHandler in two different @RestController classes?

-> It's just a matter of avoiding code duplication and improving reusability.

Spring provides a way to define global exception handlers which will be applied to all controllers in the application (Web application context).

We can use `@ControllerAdvice` annotation to define classes which will handle global exceptions. Classes annotated with `@ControllerAdvice` can be declared explicitly as Spring beans or **auto-detected via classpath scanning**.

For more info [ControllerAdvice](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/ControllerAdvice.html)

We can define exception handlers (methods) specific to an exception  using `@ExceptionHandle` annotation. Methods annotated with `@ExceptionHandle` to be shared across multiple @Controller classes.

For more in [ExceptionHandler](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/ExceptionHandler.html)

Example of global exception handler applicable for all @Controller classes in web application context,

```
    /**
     * <p>This class is to demonstrate global exception handling in spring mvc.</p>
     * <p>This class is declared under *.web package, so it will be detected by dispatcher servlet and will be part of web application context created by dispatcher servlet</p>
     * <br/> It make more sese to declare these classes as a part of web app context and not part of root context because, we do not want these classes to be able to get injected into root context beans.
     * <br/>
     * This class can handle exceptions thrown from <br/>
     *</t> 1. All controllers in application. <br/>
     *</t> 2. All interceptors in applications.
     * 
     *
     */
    @ControllerAdvice // We can us attributes of this annotation to limit which controllers this exception handler advise should apply/advise. If we we do not specify, it will be applied to all controllers in web application context.
    public class GlobalExceptionHandler {

        @ResponseStatus(code = HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND)
        @ExceptionHandler(SpittleNotFoundException.class)
        public ModelAndView handleSpittleNotFoundException(SpittleNotFoundException exception) {
            // all code in this is exactly similar to request handling code in controller
            ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView("errors/notFound");
            modelAndView.addObject("errorMessage", exception.getMessage());
            return modelAndView;
        }

        @ResponseStatus(code = HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR)
        @ExceptionHandler(Throwable.class)
        public String handleGenericException(Throwable exception) {
            return "errors/internalServerError";
        }
    }
```

Spring docs links,

1. [Controller Advice](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/web.html#mvc-ann-controller-advice)
2. [Exceptions Handlers](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/web.html#mvc-ann-exceptionhandler)